# White screen after downloading app from TestFlight - Expo

Tags: ios, react-native, metro-bundler

I am facing a weird issue in one of my apps where when I build the app using

```
expo build:ios
```

and then upload the app using

> Transporter

When I download the app from TestFlight it `opens up with a white screen`. I have tried running app in production mode on the device using below commands

```
expo run:ios -d
```

after that in bundler press `p` to switch into the production mode. It is working fine on the local using local IP address.

When I export the `.ipa` file and try to run on the device it gives me

> The app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be
> verified

Has anyone has faced the same issue before? Why it is not showing any error?

Some info: I am using expo managed bare workflow

**app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Myndfulness",
    "slug": "myndfulness",
    "owner": "**************************",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#fff",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 300
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "app.myndfulness",
      "buildNumber": "29",
      "usesAppleSignIn": true,
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
      "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
      "config": {
        "googleSignIn": {
          "reservedClientId": "**************************"
        }
      },
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "app.myndfulness",
      "versionCode": 4,
      "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "config": {
        "googleSignIn": {
          "certificateHash": "270AA8A33CF59E92614AF182C917CAF866D38719"
        }
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png",
      "config": {
        "firebase": {
          "apiKey": "**************************",
          "authDomain": "**************************",
          "projectId": "**************************",
          "storageBucket": "**************************",
          "messagingSenderId": "441874631846",
          "appId": "**************************",
          "measurementId": "G-KX9BYB1D1Z"
        }
      }
    },
    "packagerOpts": {
      "sourceExts": [ "js", "json", "ts", "tsx", "jsx", "vue"]
    }
  }
}
```

**eas.json**

```
{
  "build": {
    "production": {
      "releaseChannel": "production"
    },
    "release": {
      "releaseChannel": "production"
    },
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "releaseChannel": "staging-dev"
    },
    "team": {
      "releaseChannel": "staging-team",
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "app-bundle"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "appleId": "**************************",
        "ascAppId": "1579481834",
        "appleTeamId": "**************************",
        "sku": "app.myndfulness"
      },
      "android": {
        "serviceAccountKeyPath": "./google-services.json",
        "track": "internal"
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.35.0",
    "requireCommit": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need integration with Sentry to be able track your JS error, because whitescreen occured because there's a break on your JS

or maybe you can using https://github.com/a7ul/react-native-exception-handler and alert the error to be able to know what makes your app white screen

Answer (score 1):

For anyone, having the same issue I resolved it by uploading the build using [EAS](https://expo.dev/eas)

```
eas build -p=ios —auto-submit —clear-cache
```

To know about more available options with EAS use

```
eas build --help
```

Comment: No luck for me. My app is just blank and then crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem yesterday, and after struggling for hours, I tried installing the packages with Yarn instead of npm, and the issue was resolved.